# Having trouble with Verilog inout wires

Tags: verilog

For the record, I'm a complete Verilog newbie. I'm writing a module that uses a few bidirectional buses.

```
inout wire [KEY_SIZE-1:0] prevKey;
inout wire [TAG_SIZE-1:0] prevTag;

inout wire [KEY_SIZE-1:0] nextKey;
inout wire [TAG_SIZE-1:0] nextTag;
```

I know how I read things off of the bus, but how do I write something onto it? If I use an assign statement to a `reg`, will the value of the `reg` get clobbered when new data comes onto the wire? Is dealing with an `inout` port worth the hassle, or should I just make an `input` and and `output` bus for each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I use an assign statement to a reg...

This statement doesn't really make sense, you don't do assignments to regs, you do assignments to wires.

Simple example of driving an inout wire:

```
inout wire bidir_wire;

reg drive_value;
reg drive_enable;
reg something;

assign bidir_wire = drive_enable ? drive_value : 1'bz; 

always @(posedge clk) begin
    drive_value  <= ... ;  //assign a drive value based on some criteria
    drive_enable <= ...;
    something    <= bidir_wire; //do something with the input value
end
```

Comment: So despite assigning to `drive_value` (which is in turn mirrored in `bidir_wire`), you can still read the old value of `bidir_wire`?

Comment: @AndyShulman, sorry meant to make those statements nonblocking. So whenever the clock edge rises, the old value of bidir_wire is latched into register 'something', and the new value of the drive_value is latched in, overriding the wire.